# What does 'INT' - 'INT' denotes in c++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, integer

What does this statement really means in C++?

```
int num= '3'-'0';//or any integer in place of 3.
```

Comment: Take the value of `'3'` of type `char`, promote it to `int`, do the same thing with `'0'`, then subtract. Digits are consecutive by the standard, so the result is always `3`.

Comment: For ascii encoding [see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chars are just integers, so `'3'` is a `char` but it also has an integer value. But that value is not 3, on my system the value of `'3'` is 51 and the value of `'0'` is 48 so `'3' - '0'` equals 3.

Now on your system the values of `'3'` and `'0'` might be different. But C++ guarantees that whatever the values of the chars `'3' - '0'` must equal 3. And in the same way it guarantees that all the digits work similarly, so `'9' - '5'` must equal 4, etc.

Comment: I didn’t know that C++ required this. Do you know what part of the spec guarantees this?

Comment: @templatetypedef In this draft version http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf it's specified in section 5.3.3 `the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous`

Answer (score 1):

The operator `-` is the subtraction operator. If you think about integers as positions in a [number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line), then subtraction is the distance between the operands. The distance between 3 and 1 is 2, and distance between 2 and 0 is 2.

Characters are integers. Each numeric value represents some symbol, as specified in the [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Instead of a number line, we can now think of a line of symbols. Subtraction is now the distance between the symbols on this line.

When you subtract a symbol from itself, you get the distance 0. So for example, `'0' - '0'` is 0. Knowing that all integer symbols are consecutive on the symbol line:

```
// symbol line of an example encoding
..... / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; .....
```

you may notice that the distance between any digit symbol, and the symbol `'0'` is same as  the number that the digit represents. For example, the distance of `'3'` from `'0'` is 3.

How could this be useful? Well, it is quite often useful to know the numeric value that a digit symbol represents. In particular, this is used when converting a string of digits into a number.